# Generating OData $metadata with the schema http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx

Tags: visual-studio, odata

When I use ODataLib 5.6.1 to generate an OData metadata document like this:

```
var eModel = new Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel();
.... 
...WriteMetadataDocument()
....
```

I get the following xml:

**edmx document 1**:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx" Version="3.0">
...
</edmx:Edmx>
```

However [this](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/%24metadata) metadata (http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata) has a different schema:

**edmx document 2**:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
...
</edmx:Edmx>
```

How can I generate metadata looking like the document 2? My motivation is that many OData clients (e.g. Visual Studio's "Add Service Reference") don't seem to recognize the document 1.

Comment: I read from here (http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/[MC-CSDL].pdf) that document 1 corresponds to CSDL 3.0, while document 2 coresponds to CSDL 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I figured out the trick (using SetEdmVersion):

```
var eModel = new Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel();
...
eModel.SetEdmVersion(new Version(1, 0));
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out why our custom OData service wasn't able to be added as a service reference, I suspected it was the OData version and after comparing with other valid OData services, this solved my problem completely! Very good find.